# Best practice for setting configuration settings

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some Game Objects with public properties that are set in the editor.

Now, I want to change it so some of these are loaded from a configuration file.

For example:
userForm script has public string uploadURL.

What is the best practice. I could have a script at Start() that reads the configuration and sets the properties of each game object. But, how could I guarantee my settings runs before the other objects?

Is there an alternative?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `Awake()` method runs before `Start()`, which might help you somewhat.  You can also edit the order that particular scripts run in from the Unity IDE (guaranteeing that a particular component runs first in a given update cycle).

However, if you're loading configuration from files, you might find it easier (and more efficient) to have a single overarching "Configuration Loader" that sets up all of your GameObjects from one configuration file, rather than having each component read from a file separately.

Comment: YEs, that's what I have. A single configuration loader for the app. I was concerned that Awake() called on game object creation may now have guaranteed all objects were created. But I will look at the script ordering capability.